# Strange array run-time error

Tags: java, arrays

I've just started learning Java and I've run into a problem that I can't solve in the following code where I'm playing around with arrays.

The program is supposed to print out the numbers 1-9 twice, which the program does. However, every 4-6 times (approximately) I run the program the console prints out an additional number behind the two lists of 1-9. Why does this occur and how do I prevent this from happening?

Thank you in advance!
Cheers!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTesting
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[][] matrix = new int[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    int [][] newArray = solver(matrix);
    for(int k = 0; k < newArray.length; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < newArray[k].length; l++)
        {
            System.out.println(newArray[k][l]);
        }
    }
}
public static int[][] solver(int[][] matrix)
{
    return matrix;  
}
}
```

Comment: I smashed the run button to death an it always just prints 1-9 twice. No additional numbers. :/

Comment: And, I thought today am going to learn/ discover something new about arrays.

Comment: What's the value of this additional number?

Comment: That makes it even stranger, I also smashed the run button another 100 times and now it works as it should. But the only thing I changed from when it didn't work was the class name and I re-compiled it, I didn't change anything else in the code.

Comment: The IDE might have been running stale code. IDE software will do this from time to time and that's why when you have behavior that is truly unexplainable it's good to restart the IDE, clean and recompile.

Comment: It gave different numbers between 1 and 9, and I tested it many times and every 4-6 times it would give me a strange result. But it seems to be working now so its left me confused but maybe there is simple explanation, but I cant see what that could possibly be. Thanks for your guys time and help though! Sorry there didn't turn out to be a problem there anymore though!

Comment: Ok thank you! That would explain it!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you call [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29), your code would look something like

```
int[][] matrix = new int[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
int[][] newArray = solver(matrix);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code from the terminal, the script ran it 100 times. There is no additional number. If you are working in an IDE, I suggest you press the Clean Project button. If that doesn't work, you can restart the IDE and as a last resort, clear the cache.